# SPRING ISSUE : Cant list properties that has @CustomAnnotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

When the project starts , the idea is to seach all de variables that has @AppProperty annotation asign.

Testing, I can't get the list, and I always get an empty list. I am using the getBeansWithAnnotation () function from ApplicationContext. My theory is that at the time the search is executed, they have not yet been loaded, but I cannot confirm that it is that.

This is the beginning of the project, where I use the @EventListener to run after lifting the project.

[Beggining Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avds4.png)

There the ApplicationPropertyService is called where I try to get the list of all the properties that contain the @AppProperty annotation

[Service Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7NbO.png)

These are the two properties that I want to appear to me.

```js
public interface ApplicationProperties {

    @AppProperty( key = "version" , value ="1.0.0" , active = true)
    public String APP_VERSION = "version";
    
    @AppProperty( key = "checkVersion" , value = "true" , active = true)
    public String APP_CHECK_VERSION = "checkVersion";
    
}
```

@Annotation

```js
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface AppProperty {

    String key();
    
    String value() default "";
    
    boolean active() default false;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have several problems in your code.

First, as you can see in the `getBeansWithAnnotation` method [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeansWithAnnotation-java.lang.Class-), it will only detect **class** level annotations:

> Find all beans whose Class has the supplied Annotation type, returning a Map of bean names with corresponding bean instances.

But, you are trying to apply them to a class in which only fields has been annotated, and with an annotation defined and only suitable for field level - as per the `@Target(ElementType.FIELD)` - annotation.

You should create a new annotation suitable to be applied to a type, `@Target(ElementType.TYPE)`, and apply the class you need to be identified by Spring with this new annotation.

In addition, that class, `ApplicationProperties` in your example, should annotated with something that allows Spring to find it. You can use, for instance, `@Component`, `@Service`, etcetera, or you can define ...) or defined `ApplicationProperties` as a `@Bean` somewhere in your application context: `getBeansWithAnnotation` will only provide you information about Spring **beans**.

Finally, Spring provides a feature rich property based configuration system out of the box based on the `PropertySource` abstraction and related stuff. Please, review the [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#spring-core), it is plenty of information regarding this topic.

Comment: @RodrigoGonzalezArias Were you able to try any of the suggested approaches?